# Security requirements required in login system through XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php, security

I have created a login/signup system which submits values to a `php` file and connects the database to login. I'm concerned about the security of my login system from the **client side**, so security in the `login.php` and `script.js`. What are the **things** I need to take into consideration to make a secure login system. As in the security in the `XMLHttpRequest` or in the input fields of the **client side**.

`login.php`

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>LOGIN</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
            header ("Location: index.html");
            exit();
        }
    ?>
    <input id="inserted_id" type="text" placeholder="Account Name/e-mail" />
    <p>
    <input id="inserted_password" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <p>
    <button id="login_submit" type="submit">Login</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`script.js:`

```
document.getElementById("login_submit").onclick = function () {
        var inserted_id = document.getElementById("inserted_id").value;
        var inserted_password = document.getElementById("inserted_password").value;
        http_request("web_includes/login.inc.php?inserted_id=" + inserted_id + "&inserted_password=" + inserted_password);
    }

    function http_request(url) {
        var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xml.open("GET", url);
        xml.onload = function () {
            if (xml.responseText == "SUCCESS") {
                window.open("index.html", "_self", "", false);
            } else {
                console.log("FAIL");
            }
        }
        xml.send(null);
    }
```

Comment: Not sure how it is any different than a form submission on a page?

Comment: I need to check for empty fields and then show `jquery` dialogs. So i'm not using the form submission method. But is there any security required for `http` method from the client side?

Comment: I was saying there is nothing different in security. Both use http requests to send data to the server.

Comment: So wait in conclusion, should there be any security on the client side? Or is it that security is required on the server side only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unsure about XMLHttpRequest's, but research;

- **CSP**:  Content Security Policy, Which is specified
  in the HTML Meta Tags.
  ..(to Block or negate Cross-site-Scripting aswell as other threats).  ..................................https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JbfNWg6JS4U
- **CORS**: Cross Origin resource Sharing. 
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
- **Sha256** & other versions.
- **Hashing+Salt+pepper** are a similar concept. many videos on youtube about   ................this....
- Also Research. **Nonce's** (Not the Jail kind).
  it stands for a Number which is used once, 
  Similar to a key. That only your website & Database will have access to or the full number atleast..
- (Change XMLHttpRequest to XMLHttpsRequest with the S meaning secure.)
  Not viable apparently. or Automatically chosen.

& Could possibly put your whole Login form inside of an Iframe Which you can then specify individual Security attributes on. through the 'Sandboxing' feature. 
(Not sure this is necessary if you implement the others or good practice, but it might add an extra layer of frustration to any potential attacker.)

for the PHP side aswell as any Javascript files use RegEx functions to block any attempt to add code;         Blocking;

```
   {Z}()[]^></#..etc.....
```

Just thought of another thing that came to mind. There are websites such as File2hd where you can download websites entire js/css/php/json/ajax etc.... 
There is a way to block these requests but thats something you'd have to research... it is a very handy site though for analyzing & learning other peoples code...

.php file extension cannot generally be viewed or altered from client side,
unless they are very skilled.. But CSP is your best bet with hash+salt+pepper + RegEx...

A combination of any of the above should make it farely secure... Kind Regards Tao.
Hope this helps :)..

Comment: There is no `XMLHttpsRequest` object in js. The `XMLHttpRequest` can do both `http` and `https` requests. Suggesting something where you don’t know if it is necessary, or good practice, and where you are not sure if it help in anyway is not a good ideas if it is about security. Preventing code injection is important, but RegEx won’t be that helpful. It is more about where and how user input can be used, and hoeing has to be escaped.

Comment: I was just trying to bullet point aspects that I've been researching to try and help the Original poster. So he can research his own avenues of inquiry. I'm still learning myself. I didn't know XMLHttp could handle both. if it can do both? how do you sway it towards the secure version? I was just going on what i had read about websockets & other articles pertaining to security ie... changing ws to wss, changing http to https, seemed a natural conclusion that XML requests would be the same. The Iframe suggestion was just putting it in the list to see debate answers about it.

Comment: How is RegEx not that helpful? when you can implement it both client side via Javascript linked to input fields & form data. & also Server side via php? if it prevents code being parsed to the database then surely it is helpful.... Please explain? never heard of Hoeing will take a look....

Comment: If the protocol part of the url is `https` encryption is used, if it is `http` then no encryption is used. Proper escaping of untrusted data is the key-point about security. And if done correctly then code execution problems should normally only occur if you need to directly use html code provided by the user, and then you should parse that html code and only accept tags and attribute that are white listed. A RegExp will most likely miss many attack vectors or give to many false positives.

Comment: Where exactly is this whitelist specified? CSP does not accept a whitelist of acceptable HTML tags? attributes maybe, i'm only aware of vectors in a desgn/image context so i cannot comment on that..

Comment: @t.niese About Your comment above: How do you implement escaping without RegEx?

Comment: @t.niese Also RegEx does not give false positives if implemented correctly... It is either a match or no match.. it can not be both. on match it blocks or removes characters on no match it allows... I do not understand your comments please explain..

Comment: I don’t think a comment section of an answer that tries to give security tips is the right place to teach the basics of security. I’ll answer the pending questions but not any further ones, as each of the topics can und must be research and has to be understand in detail if you want to do anything security related.

Comment: Whitelisting and filtering of the html you receive by the user has to be done by you. CSP is an part of a complete security concept, like filtering using waitlists is. “Attack Vector” a commonly used term in the field of security.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188634/discussion-between-ryan-stone-and-t-niese).

Comment: Escaping is done with a simple search and replace. The complexity of a RegExp is not required. A RegExp detects/replaces what ever you defined, so it might replace/reject valid input if wrote your RegExp incorrectly (false positive) or misses some malicious input because you didn’t think about a certain possibility of injecting code and your RegExp does not detect/replaces it as of that. Or your replace logic has a flaw that would allow to create malicious output, ...

Comment: Looks like some complex stuff, but I will research and see what I can get out of it. Another thing I have seen with my code is that when I attach the `inserted_id` and `inserted_password` with the `XMLHttpRequest`'s url's params, the `inserted_id` and `inserted_password` can be seen through the `network` bar in `Inspect`. Is it okay if these values are being shown?